# Azure SaaS site - AD Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

We have hosted our application with third party authentication enabled using oAuth-OpenID connect which is working fine for Google and Facebook. Now we want to expose that to few users for testing purpose but we dont want the URL itself to be misused.
So, we added additional Authentication just to reach the site itself for preconfigured AD email addresses. But that was enabled directly in the Azure portal settings.

1) Once the user type the url in the browser, it takes to the microsoft login page. Enter the AD email address

2)It redirect to the site properly as expected

3)But here comes the problem, since the individual authentication already enabled for ather service providers, the AD token carried to the site and it started misbehaving
I want to provide AD authentication just to the entry for my site. But after that, it should not effective. How to achieve that

Comment: what's your exact concern about "the URL to be misused"?

Comment: Hi, We shared our site url to the test users and they are going to demo to the other users. They can just see the url and try to attempt to access the site and we dont want them to do that, so to reach the site itself, we put an entry level authentication which is temporary until we roll it out. hope it answers your questions. Thank you

Comment: IMHO that's unnecessary or an overkill. You may better change the url every release or every week instead of adding another component that won't be part of your actual product.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to expose the web app to specific Azure AD user for testing purpose.

If I understood correctly, in this scenario the web app can interact with Azure AD via OpenID connect just like the Google and Facebook instead using settings on Azure portal. And if you also doesn't want to Google and Facebook account could access the web app, you should remove the corresponding authentication middle-ware. And to limit the Azure AD user to access the web app, you can enable **Enabled for users to sign-in** feature like below:
[image]

Then we can add the users via **Users and groups** to enable the users we want to allow to access the web app.